# Does React Native have an alternative to console.log that doesn't recur through nested objects or ones with circular references?

Tags: ios, macos, debugging, react-native, console.log

I've noticed that whenever I use `console.log()` in my React Native project to output unknown objects, that objects containing recursive references can lock up the simulator, or even my whole system if it's already a bit bogged down.

Is this a known problem with RN? Is there also an alternative to `console.log()` which doesn't recur through the whole object tree?

(If it makes a difference I'm working on a Mac with the iOS simulator)

Comment: have you try to use ide to debug such as vscode debugger?

Comment: @GaneshCauda: I'm using VSCode but I'm new to it and haven't played with the debugger yet. But it is hanging whether I have the iOS simulator hooked up to the Terminal or to the Google Chrome debugger, so I think it's due to their internal implementation of `console.log`

Comment: I just thought that I could try `.toString()`

Comment: you can try 2 different methods with the vscode debugger, one is by using fully integrated debugger(packager + debugger) or you can use your own packager and attach the vscode debugger to that packager, the second one is more stable in my experience. If you are using exponent, you can use this RN debugger + Expo as explained in this article https://www.gravitywell.co.uk/latest/rd/posts/react-native-debugger-expo-awesome/